# Direct3D in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, directx, direct3d, slimdx

Is there any way to use Direct3D scene in Silverlight application?

We are successfully using Direct3D (through SlimDX) in WPF with D3DImage class. Is there equivalent in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight support for 3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547098.aspx) uses XNA.

So the actual class D3DImage is NOT available in Silverlight instead it uses the [DrawingSurface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.drawingsurface%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Switching from SlimDX to XNA is quite a work, with the code base we currently have... millions of rows of code. So I think there would be demand for a SlimDX/Silverlight adapter if someone programmed such.

Comment: I doubt that. Due to Silverlight being, well, not actively being promoted by Microsoft... Microsoft's dropping of Silverlight and XNA sort of indicates that 3D development is moving (back) to the C++ world of DirectX on 'all' platforms.

Comment: ...not to mention the 3D experience in Silverlight is as good as broken from the end users point of view: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/12/10/Why-Silverlight-5s-3D-is-(almost)-useless.aspx